# HP Standalone iLo Integrated Remote Console: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found

Tags: ilo

Does [HP Standalone iLo Integrated Remote Console](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=MTX_4f842ceb31cf48d392e22705a8) work with iLO2?

I can log in via the web UI, and use the Java viewers just fine.

When I try to connect with the standalone .NET app, it gives the error:

> The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Does this utility not work with iLO 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [installation instructions](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=MTX_4f842ceb31cf48d392e22705a8):

> This utility requires the following minimum firmware/configuration
>   revisions:
>
> HP ProLiant or Integrity server with iLO 3 iLO 3 firmware v1.15 or
>   later

No, this tool will not work with an ILO2 management processor.

Comment: No biggie. I didn't even realize this tool existed.

Comment: I've used it on iLO 4 servers and it is much nicer than any of the web-based stuff. Too bad it doesn't work for my G6.  Of course once you get the OS installed, it's unnecessary, buy I'm evaluating hypervisor solutions, so I'm re-installing occasionally.

Answer (score 1):

It did work with Ilo 2 in older firmwares, but with the lastest Ilo 2 updates it failed. I know it worked for the 2.15 ilo version. The 2.27 nowadays indeed does not support it, so https is the only option.